# How to reproduce owasp dependency-check example of dependency report

Tags: maven, dependencies, owasp

I want to check if my project dependencies have any updates.
I've used

```
versions:dependency-updates-report
```

But I have some performance problems with it which I was unable to solve. Now I'm trying to use

```
org.owasp.dependency-check-maven:check
```

But I could not reproduce their example:

[image: https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-cli/dependency-updates-report.html]

I'm getting similar look but I can't get 4 last columns (Next Version, Next Incremental, Next Minor, Next Major) which is most important for me.

How to reproduce this example?

Answer (score 1):

You will not reproduce the given report with `org.owasp.dependency-check-maven` because the shown report is created with `versions-maven-plugin`.

This are two different plugins.

`org.owasp.dependency-check-maven` is to find vulnerabilities according to the NVD in dependencies whereas `versions-maven-plugin` is for checking for newer versions, independent of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

*(full disclosure - I am the founder of meterian)*

You may want to consider a commercial product like [sourceclear](https://sourceclear.io/), [snyk](https://snyk.io/) or [meterian](https://meterian.io).

The [meterian client](https://meterian.io/the_client.html#try-now) is very easy to use, you can quickly check any maven or gradle project with no changes to the code: get the client, cd into the project folder, run it, see the results.

It's free for open source projects, badges are available for GitHub, and at the moment commercial use is not charged.

Hope this helps.